# Backbutton support for Navbar from Bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, browser-history

I've [reworked](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/tree/gh-pages) the Navbar of Twitter Bootstrap a bit to support the back button. So this is a simple single page solution which does not require server side processing. [Try here](http://graphhopper.com). Now I would like to create links from within one tab to another tab. I've done this via

```
// make links with data-toggle outside of mytabs working
$('#main a[data-toggle]').click(function (e) {
   $(this).tab('show');
});
```

And just need to mark the links in the HTML with data-toggle=tab:

```
<a href="#download" data-toggle="tab">Download</a>
```

It still works, e.g. [try](http://graphhopper.com) Download in the left-bottom corner, but the new tab is not highlighted anymore somehow. (worked before. investigating.) Additionally when I would like to use a dropdown but the old tab is still highlighted, see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iCeR.png

**My question: Is there an 'official' or just better way to make navigating tabs for Bootstrap working? I.e. where highlighting, back browser support, dropdown and onload behaviour is implemented properly.**

Update:
Dropdown is still an issue but the highlight-on-normal-link-click issue seems to be fixed when you do:

```
$('#main a[data-toggle]').click(function (e) {
  document.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Or should I try easytabs which [seems to work](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/#twitter-bootstrap) out of the box with bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long Answer: Bootstrap is at its base just a CSS framework. Yes, it includes some jQuery plugins. But if you look closely at those, you will notice most of them are not rich with functionality.

So no, the sort of interactivity you are looking for is not built in to Bootstrap directly. The path you are on is the correct one - find a compatible plug-in, or do it yourself. This may seem like a shortcoming of Bootstrap, but it really isn't. From a Javascript perspective, they are leaving it to you to decide how to best implement these sorts of things, instead of locking you in to one particular way.